# Can we Migrate TFS 2015 to Azure DevOps Directly?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm planning to move to Azure DevOps. Currently we have TFS2015 in house. Based on the article it says we have to migrate to TFS 2018 before migrating to Azure DevOps. Can't we migrate from TFS 2015 to Azure DevOps?

Comment: "the article"? *Which article*? Are you referring to the [Team Foundation Server to Azure DevOps Services Migration Guide and Database Import Tooling](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54274) provided by Microsoft? If so, why do you think Microsoft would be in error talking about performing a migration between two of it's own products?

Comment: yes, i am referring to the same article. But not sure if we have work around to get the Migration from TFS 2015 --> Azure DevOps. Migrating to 2018 add extra effort.

Comment: Also not sure whether we should purchase license for TFS 2018 Migration.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/articles/migration-overview?view=azdevops) migration paths only apply to:

The TFS Database Import Service supports the two latest releases of TFS at a given time. Releases include updates and major releases. Currently the following versions of TFS are supported for import:

1. TFS 2018 Update 2
2. TFS 2018 Update 3 & Update 3.1

So you have to upgrade before attempting this migration

Comment: Thank you. Can you confirm whether i need licensed 2018 installer for Migration?

Comment: sorry, that I dont know

Comment: No. Trial will do.

Answer (score 1):

All of the above answers are correct.  But there is an alternative IF you only want your repositories.  If you want to migrate your source code repositories:

Option 1)  If TFVC (TFS Version Control) - Basically create a local workspace, copy it into a new local git repo, create a new Azure DevOps git repo, then push local git repo to new empty git repo, repeat as necessary.

Option 2) If TFS 2015 is hosting Git repos already, then just clone the git repos with all branches and tags, create a new Azure DevOps git repo, then push local git repo to new empty git repo with all branches and tags, repeat as necessary (script is more involved but can be automated, this is what I did).

We were only using TFS 2015 for version control only, so we opted just to move one project at a time.

Comment: Hi we are having TFS 2015 and we would like to only move TFS source code to Azure Devops git repository. Do i still need to upgrade to TFS 2018 or it is not needed?

Comment: It depends on the migration tool, but most likely you WILL need to upgrade to TFS 2018.  Read what @omarv74 wrote below.  If you cannot do that then I suggest migrating manually.