# TFS 2015 to Azure DevOps service Migration

Tags: azure-devops, migration, tfs-2015, azure-devops-server-2019

I am trying to migrate from TFS 2015 to Azure DevOps service. Can I migrate it directly? Please suggest if there are any steps for migration.

Comment: As I know you can't migrate it directly. Check this [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54397059/can-we-migrate-tfs-2015-to-azure-devops-directly), you have to upgrade the tfs like jessehouwing suggested below first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the latest [Azure DevOps Migration Guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/migrate/). At the time of writing, you'll need to upgrade to Azure DevOps Server 2019rtw or 2019.1:

[image]

And the migration tool may find some blocking issues that need to be resolved prior to migration.